# What is this plant with buds?

Tags: identification, indoors, outdoor, bud

It's been growing for a few months -- first as a little seedling in my polka dot plant pot, and now I have it outside. When I put it outside, it shot way up and started getting these little green buds. What is it? When it was smaller I thought it was a geranium, but now that it's matured I don't think it is...

[image: Picture of plant]

Comment: It looks a bit like a nettle, with the serrated oval leaves and the buds. Comparing images online, it looks like both stinging nettle and hemp nettle might be a match.

Answer (score 1):

As the plant grew, my plant identification app helped me realize that it's a nipplewort.